# Vagrant Reports Different Installed GuestAdditions version

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I've seem posts on the Internet about similar issues like this one, but I couldn't get it to work.

Host OS: Mac OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)
Guest OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Virtualbox 5.0.8
Vagrant 1.7.4

$ vagrant reload

```
...
...
...
```

```
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.3.10
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.8
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
GuestAdditions seems to be installed (5.0.8) correctly, but not running.
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.3.10
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.8
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
stdin: is not a tty
Usage: service  | --status-all | [ service_name [ command | --full-restart ] ]
bash: line 3: vboxadd: command not found
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.3.10
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.8
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
stdin: is not a tty
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
You should restart your guest to make sure the new modules are actually used

Restarting VM to apply changes...
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.10
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/martin/VMs/cloudperf
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

However, the following commands show the right information:

```
$ vagrant vbguest --status
GuestAdditions 5.0.8 running --- OK.
```

```
$ VBoxManage guestproperty get  /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version
Value: 5.0.8
```

I do have other two vagrant VMs running CentOS without any problems.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm have the exactly same issue. Have you found any resolutions yet?

Answer (score 1):

I get:

```
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.3.20
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.10   
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
GuestAdditions 5.0.10 running --- OK.
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.3.20
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.10
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
```

Sometimes all is fine, but more frequently now a problem is reported. Seems to be flaky results from querying VirtualBox about version.

My VirtualBox is Version 5.0.10 r104061; vbguest version 0.11.0

`vbguest --status` gives me:

```
$ vagrant vbguest --status
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   4.3.20
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.0.10
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
GuestAdditions 5.0.10 running --- OK.
```

It's nonsense; virtual box is 5.0.10

`vboxmanage --version` gives me 5.0.10r104061, which is correct.

Therefore this appears to be a vbguest bug.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to upgrade everything. VirtualBox, VirtualBoxAddons and Vagrant.
If you can't connect to VM using Vagrant just open VirtualBox and start it from here.