# Vagrant issue with GuestAdditions version

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I'm trying to run a `Vagrantfile` on my Ubuntu server.
I got the following error message:

```
An error occurred during installation of VirtualBox Guest Additions 6.1.26. Some functionality may not work as intended.
In most cases it is OK that the "Window System drivers" installation failed.
Unmounting Virtualbox Guest Additions ISO from: /mnt
Cleaning up downloaded VirtualBox Guest Additions ISO...
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 6.1.26
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 6.1.26
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.2.0
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 6.1.26
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Restarting VM to apply changes...
```

I used the following commands to install Virtualbox and Vagrant:

```
# Install VirtualBox
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libxmu6 libxt6 -y
sudo apt-get install virtualbox -y

# Install vagrant and its plugins
curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vagrant -y
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
vagrant plugin install vagrant-disksize
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager
```

Versions installed:

```
Vagrant 2.2.18
Virtualbox 6.1.26
```

The installation is stuck on:

```
Installing rsync to the VM...
==> worker-customer: Rsyncing folder: /home/worker/ => /vagrant
```

Which seems logic as the Guest additions are not working properly.

How to fix version mismatch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vagrant-vbguest [Github page](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) says

> If you're lucky, vagrant-vbguest does not require any configuration

but there appear to be several reports of the [same happening with different versions](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest/issues/300). There's an example of vagrantfile, which has a commented-out line:

```
  # config.vbguest.iso_path = "../relative/path/to/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso"
```

Uncommenting this and setting the correct relative line should fix the issue. According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/997849/vagrant-reports-different-installed-guestadditions-version) discussion updating the vagrant-vbguest to latest version with command

```
vagrant plugin update
```

seems to have fixed the issue for multiple users.

[This SU community member](https://superuser.com/a/1112479/330527) says that the issue can be resolved by installing Guest Additions from within the guest OS.

More possible solutions can be found by googling the message

```
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version
```

All versions of VBox Guest Additions can be downloaded from this [virtualbox.org download page](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Virtualbox says version is `6.1.26`. I've tried to install the VBGA 5.2.0 but I still have error ` Guest Additions Version: 5.2.0 r68940 VirtualBox Version: 6.1`.

Comment: I updated the answer